# Django Template: Simple Variable in a Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following block of HTML code:

```
<header>
    <div>....</div>
</header>
```

On one page only, I need to have:

```
<header class="something">
    <div>....</div>
</header>
```

Is there a simple way of doing this rather than doing too many overrides?

Comment: you mean to say remove redundancy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
<header class="{% if a_flag %}something{% else %}somethingelse{% endif %}">
    <div>....</div>
</header>
```

where **a_flag** is a variable in the current context.